# XSL - How to match or select empty element to insert generated content

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm converting an XML file to HTML using XSLT. Part of the conversion includes outputting a navbar. I have some code that walks through the tree and grabs the title of each section and outputs it as a list item. However, certain types of sections are empty and completely generated. I need to be able to insert a default title into the navbar when those sections occur. I'm using `xsl:choose` to insert the titles, but I have not been able to find a way to match on the empty element.

I have looked at other solutions mentioned here, including testing for `my-empty-element[. = '']` and `my-empty-element[not(text())]`, but these have not worked for me. A simplified version of my XML document:

```
<book>
  <section id="s1">
    <title>Section 1 Title</title>
    <!-- Other stuff here -->
  </section>
  <section-empty id="s2"/> <!-- My generated section -->
  <section id="s3">
    <title>Section 3 Title</title>
    <!-- Other stuff here -->
  </section>
</book>
```

***Edited to add further explanation:** During regular processing of the book, each section is broken out into a separate file. As each section is processed, I include `<xsl:call-template name="navbar"/>` so the navbar is actually called from the section.*

To confirm, the empty sections have a different name than the regular sections. Here's a simplified version of my XSL:

```
<xsl:template name="navbar">
<!-- I call this template in at the location of the navbar in my HTML document -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/book" mode="nav"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/book" mode="nav">
  <nav class="mainnav"><ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="section | section-empty" mode="nav"/>
  </ul></nav>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section | section-empty" mode="nav">
  <li><a>
    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="./@id"/></xsl.attribute>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::section"><xsl:value-of select="./title/text()"/></xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="self::section-empty"><xsl:text>Generated Title</xsl:text></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>
  </a></li>
</xsl:template>
```

I've also tried creating a separate template to match `book/section-empty[.='']` but that didn't make any difference. My current output looks like this:

```
<nav><ul>
  <li><a href="s1">Section 1 Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="s3">Section 3 Title</a></li>
</ul</nav>
```

I appreciate any help anyone can offer.

*Edited to include close tag for `<xsl:attribute name="id">` in original example.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was a typo in an element name in my template match. I had an uppercase letter where a lowercase letter should be. I missed it when examining my code. Martin Honnen confirmed my code should work and encouraged a better sample for troubleshooting, which helped me find my error.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear why you don't manage to match directly on the element names you say you have:

```
<xsl:template match="/book" >
  <nav class="mainnav"><ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="section | section-empty" />
  </ul></nav>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
  <li>
      <a href="{@id}">
          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
      </a>
  </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section-empty">
    <li>
        <a href="{@id}">Generated Title</a>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbeV

Comment: I looked through my code and tested it again to make sure I didn't inadvertently introduce an error. But everything looks right. It must have something to do with the system I'm using. I'm working with a system that uses an embedded SAX parser. I'm limited to XSL v1.0 and have to squeeze my XSL in under the covers and the system limits where I can do that. I'm trying to work around it by calling in this template, but it never gives me the generated title for the empty section. I was hoping there might be another way to match to the empty element. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I didn't really use anything XSLT 3 specific other than `html-version` in `xsl:output` but that is easily fixed and then an XSLT 1 processor works fine: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbeV/1. It is not clear which limits your system implements but your posted code is not even minimal working code as there is a start tag `<xsl:attribute name="id">` that is nowhere being closed. So you might need to reduce and complement the code to a minimal but complete samples so that others can reproduce the problem, otherwise it is hard to tell what goes wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. The missing ```<xsl:attribute>``` close tag was because I missed it when typing my small sample. I edited my original question to fix it. This is a representative sample that removes all of the other code that is doing unrelated things, but I'll take my original code and reduce it and edit my original question rather than try to replicate it in a vague sample. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: In reducing the code, I found a typo in an element name in a template's match... a capitalized letter than should have been lowercase. I had seen it before and thought I had fixed it, but apparently not. Thank you for confirming the code was correct and encouraging me to make a more useful sample. Without that suggestion, I likely would have missed this for some time.